# Open marker / infowindow from outside?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I'm adding markers to my Google Map like this:

```js
    function createMarker(location, info) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: location
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
            if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: info, title: 'test' });
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
```

How can I access and open the markers without a manual click on the map?

I tried to save the `marker` object and do a `marker.click()` but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added:

```
var markers = new Array();

function getMarkerbyLocation(location) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        if (markers[i].getPosition().lat() == location.lat() && markers[i].getPosition().lng() == location.lng())
            return markers[i];
    }
}
```

Modified:

```
function createMarker(location, info) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: location
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
        if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: info });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    // Modification here!
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

Some event on the page executes the following:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(getMarkerbyLocation(new google.maps.LatLng(53.43306, 9.98556)), 'click');
```